# Select distinct * error mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
mysql> select * from abc;
+---+------+------+
| A | B    | C    |
+---+------+------+
| 2 | 2    | 2    |
| 1 | 2    | 3    |
| 3 | 3    | 2    |
| 4 | 3    | 3    |
+---+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> select count(distinct *)
    -> from abc
    -> group by a;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)
from abc
group by a' at line 1
```

Can anyone let know the correct syntax for the **above** query?

Comment: The correct syntax for *what* query?  What results are you after?  Perhaps you just want to replace the `*` with `B, C` -- but it's ambiguous what you want to achieve.

Comment: @eggyal I'm trying to get the count of records in the table.

Comment: Surely you're trying to do more than just that, or else you wouldn't have `distinct` and `group by a`?

Comment: @Santosh V M: why do you need `GROUP BY`? What do you added it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `DISTINCT` you need to provide a column on which to use `DISTINCT`.

So, for example in your case: `SELECT DISTINCT(a) FROM abc`

You want to count the rows in the table, based on a unique value?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT a) FROM abc
```

There is no need for `GROUP BY` as the `DISTINCT` already takes care of that.

Comment: @Santosh V M: `DISTINCT *` makes no sense, none of DBMS support it

Comment: @Santosh V M: you didn't answer eggyal and my question in the comments.